# Как поместить сокращенную запись условия if внутрь html?

Tags: php, html

Есть поле `input`

```
$field .= '<input type="text" name="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" value="' . 
esc_attr( $value ) . '" placeholder="' . $args['placeholder'] . '" ' . 
$args['maxlength'] . ' /></p>' . $after;
```

Хочу добавить в него при определенном значении флажка `$required` и условия значение обязательное/не обязательное.

Но, вот такое решение краткой записи условия `if` приводит к ошибке. 
А как будет правильно?

```
$field .= '<input type="text" name="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" value="' . 
esc_attr( $value ) . '" placeholder="' . $args['placeholder'] . '" ' . 
$args['maxlength'] . $required ? 'required="true"  /></p>' : ' /></p>' . $after;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
$field .= '<input type="text" name="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" value="' . 
esc_attr( $value ) . '" placeholder="' . $args['placeholder'] . '" ' . 
$args['maxlength'] . ($required ? ' required="true"':'').'/></p>'.$after;
```

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, тернарный оператор - это **не** "сокращенная запись оператора if".
Во-вторых, HTML надо выводить как есть, а не колупаться со строками в пхп

```
<input type="text" name="<?=esc_attr( $key )?>" value="<?=esc_attr( $value )?>" 
       placeholder="<?=$args['placeholder']?>" maxlength=<?=$args['maxlength']?>
       <?=$required ? 'required="true" : ""?> /></p>
<?=$after?>
```